# Centralizer of a group is the intersection of Stabilizers

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $C(S)=\{g\in G\mid gs=sg,\,\forall s\in S\}$. (This set is called the centralizer of $S$ in $G$.) I need to show that it is a subgroup by recognizing it as an intersection of stabilizers under some action of $G$. I know I have to use conjugation, but I don't have idea how to proceed. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Try first to put it in words, and you may see that it is almost trivial: an element is central iff it commutes with *any* element in the group iff it belongs to the center of any element in the group. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ act on itself by conjugation. The stabilizer of $x \in G$ under this action is the set $G_x = \{s \in G : s \cdot x = sxs^{-1}=x \}$. The centralizer of $G$ in $G$ is the set $C(G) = \{c \in G: cg = gc \text{ for all } g \in G\}$. Note that we can rewrite the centralizer as $C(G) = \{c \in G: cgc^{-1} = g \text{ for all } g \in G\}$. Now show what $\bigcap_{x \in G} G_x$ is as a set and the solution should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite this as $C(S)=\{g\in G\mid gsg^{-1}=s,\,\forall s\in S\}$ with $C(S)$ being the set of all elements in $G$ which commute with every other member. Now $1\in C(S)$, since $1h=h1$ $\forall h\in G$, and so then $\forall h\in S$. Now for two elements $a,b\in C(S)$ we have $\forall s\in S$, $asa^{-1}=s$ and $bsb^{-1}=s$. Now note 
$$a^{-1}(asa^{-1})a=(a^{-1}a)s(a^{-1}a)=1s1=s$$
and
$$s=a^{-1}sa$$ 
Hence $s=a^{-1}sa=asa^{-1}$ and $C(S)$ is closed under inverses, that is if $a\in C(S)$ so is $a^{-1}\in C(S)$.

Now check it is closed under products.
\begin{align}
(ab)s(ab)^{-1}&=(ab)s(b^{-1}a^{-1})\\
&=a(bsb^{-1})a^{-1}\\
&=asa^{-1}\quad\,\,\,\,\text{since $b\in C(S)$}\\
&=s\qquad\quad\ \ \text{since $a\in C(S)$}
\end{align}
therefore $ab\in C(S)$, and $C(S)$ is closed under product taking. Hence $C(S)\subseteq G$.

The fact that $C(S)$ is a subgroup of $G$ follows by looking at how $G$ acts on its elements by group actions. The *stabilizer* of $s$ in $G$ is defined as the set $G_s=\{g\in G\mid g\cdot s=s\}$. To show it's a group first note $1\in G_s$ since $1\cdot s=s$. Now, if $a\in G_s$, 
\begin{align}
s&=1\cdot s \\
&=(a^{-1}a)\cdot s \\
&=a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot s)\\
&=a^{-1}\cdot s\qquad\quad\text{since $a\in G_s$}
\end{align}
and so $a^{-1}\in G_s$ also. Now check products: if $a,b\in G_s$ then
\begin{align}
(ab)\cdot s&=a\cdot (b\cdot s)\\
&=a\cdot s\quad\quad\,\,\text{since $b\in G_s$}\\
&=s\qquad\quad\ \,\,\text{since $s\in G_s$}
\end{align}
Hence $G_s$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The post seems to imply that they already have the fact that the stabilizer of a group is a subgroup of the acting group (if not, the OP should check this) and need to prove the statement this way, otherwise we could just skip this part and do it directly in the way that you have provided.

Comment: @abstract Exactly, the fact that centralizers are subgroups is a special case of the fact that stabilisers of actions form subgroups. I've added a proof of this from which the OP can now see how conjugation and group actions are connected.